# ExtJS property grid colour

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do I add a background colour to a property grid?

I've tried:

```
tdCls: 'red',
```

in my config but it doesn't do anything.

My full config is:

```
 xtype:'propertygrid',

        width: 80,
        header: false,
        title: 'prop grid',
        //for some reason the headers are not hiding, we may need to deal with this using CSS
        //hideHeaders: true,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        sortableColumns: false,
        nameColumnWidth: 1,
        source: record.data,
        sourceConfig: {

            periodScrumMaster: {
                editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                    tdCls: 'red',
                    store: team,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField: 'personName',
                    valueField: 'personName',

                    listeners: {
                        'expand' : function(combo) {
                            var gridvalues = this.up('propertygrid').getSource();
                            combo.getStore().clearFilter(true);
                            combo.getStore().addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
                            combo.getStore().addFilter({property: 'periodName', value: gridvalues.periodName});
                            var totalFTE = team.count();
                            console.log(totalFTE);
                            var teamStore = Ext.getStore('personPeriods');
                            console.log('store');
                            console.log(teamStore);
                        },
                    }}),
                displayName: 'Scrum Master'
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

`tdCls` on the `editor` will not work because it needs to be specified on `columns`, and `propertygrid`'s columns (and their CSS classes) are hard coded in [`Ext.grid.property.HeaderContainer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.HeaderContainer).

You still can apply your styles by adding them to the CSS classes already used on `propertygrid`. They are `x-grid-property-name` and `x-grid-cell-value` (can be seen in any DOM inspector). Example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/d4gka7aj/